# Swift и электронно-цифровая подпись

Tags: swift

интересует библиотека для создания цифровой подписи на Swift, искал в интернете, не нашел, есть какие-то варианты у кого?

Comment: посмотрите, там есть некоторые ссылки, может пригодится https://qna.habr.com/q/619460

Comment: Это вообще не то, там нет апи для работы с ключами и вообще подписью, а хотелось бы это всё ручками прописать

Comment: https://github.com/AktivCo

Comment: Не подходит, слишком много ньюансов, зарегайся там, используй на физ устроистве, привязка к какому-то сайту, интересует некоторая альтернатива CkoCrypt2 или же сам он, но на сайте плохо написан гайд по установке, там xcode времен полеозоя, я учитывая то что Apple меняет всё каждую версию я не уверен что оно вообще работает

Comment: ну по крайней мере CkoCrypt2 попробовать можно, правда я как понял этот компонент платный